# Unable to insert a row with parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I am trying following code:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=ARSLAN-LAPI\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                         "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                         "database=OTTS; " +
                         "connection timeout=30");
    conn.Open();
    String name=UserName.Text;
    String pwd=Password.Text;
    String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.user (username,password) 
                     VALUES(@username,@password)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("@username",name);
    command.Parameters.Add("@password",pwd);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    ErrorMessage.Text="Well done!";
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
     ErrorMessage.Text="You failed!" + ex.Message;
}
```

Received error that

`You failed!Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.`

Please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

[User is a reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), I strongly suggest to change that field name to something different.
However, if you still insist in using it, remember to enclose it in square brackets every time you need it.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[user] (username,password) VALUES(@username,@password)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[user] (username,password)   VALUES(@username,@password)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
command.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = name;
command.Parameters.Add("@password",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value= pwd;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```